# Run many .exe files in 1500 folders

Tags: batch-file, exe

Hello i have about 1500 folders each containing a .exe file and some associated input files. 
The process is simple, when i double click the .exe file it operates on the input files and gives a new output within the folder.

I just want to know how to do this for all 1500 folders with a script or any other way that will save my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /r %%I in (*.exe) do "%%I"
```

Note that this doesn't work if the .exe needs to run from its directory. In that case use

```
for /r %%I in (*.exe) do cd "%%~pI" && "%%I"
```

Comment: Isn't the expanded variables supposed to be `%%~dpI`? I'm anal so I'd do `FOR /R C:\ %%I IN` =D. I do believe your 2nd line of code is what he needs for the output he wants.

Comment: @Mechaflash I don't think he has to worry about changing the drive letter for every executable, but it doesn't hurt to include it.